# Parsing bold and italics markups in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, parsing, markup

How to parse something like:

```
var item = "It**e**m";
```

The result should be:

```
It<b>e</b>m
```

I'v tried to do it like this but it only matches first `**` and doesn't work with string like `**I**t**e**m` and `i**te**m`. Results should be `<b>I</b>t<b>e</b>m` and second one `i<b>te</b>m`

```
    if(item.indexOf("**") > -1){
        var separatedItem = item.split('');
        for (var i=0; i<separatedItem.length; i++){
            if(separatedItem[i] == '*'){
                separatedItem[i+2]=separatedItem[i+2].bold();
                separatedItem = separatedItem.join('');
                var newItem = separatedItem.replace(/([**])/g, '');
                return newItem;
            }
        }
    }else if(item.indexOf("__") > -1){
        var separatedItem = item.split('');
        for (var i=0; i<separatedItem.length; i++){
            if(separatedItem[i] == '_'){
                separatedItem[i+2]=separatedItem[i+2].italics();
                separatedItem = separatedItem.join('');
                var newItem = separatedItem.replace(/([__])/g, '');
                return newItem;
            }
        }
    }else{
        return item;
    }
```

Comment: If you want to match all the markups, you have to run your code in a loop until it doesn't find any matches.

Comment: But it will still match only one character not something like **word**

Comment: If you're just getting started why not use eg. Markdown syntax and an existing parser like https://github.com/evilstreak/markdown-js? If this is not an option maybe a simple regexp would suffice given you only have two tags? 
`item.replace(/\*\*(.*?)\*\*/g, "<b>$1</b>").replace(/__(.*?)__/, "<i>$1</i>")`

Comment: Thank you very much. This regexp works and solves my problem.